# C program segmentation default (core dumped)

Tags: c, gcc

I have a basic program that takes in a user command **"command varname = variable"** from a user through the readline function. It then parses the string to store each part into a string variable.  My issue that I'm having is that I'm getting an error: ***segmentation default (core dumped)*** which is supposed to be from illegal memory access, however I've gone through my program line by line on a sample input: **"set ray"** and I can't figure out where this is occurring.  My expected result is that **Command should contain set, Varname should contain ray, and Value should be NULL**  Here is the code as well as sample input and output showing the error.  I've also seen an error: ***bus (core dumped)*** show up once.  Any ideas where this error is coming from?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

/* Simple example of using gnu readline to get lines of input from a user.
   Needs to be linked with -lreadline -lcurses
   add_history tells the readline library to add the line to it's
   internal histiry, so that using up-arrow (or ^p) will allows the user
   to see/edit previous lines.
*/


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  char * s;
  char * Command;
  char * Varname;
  char * Value;

  while (s=readline("Enter Name: ")) {
    add_history(s); /* adds the line to the readline history buffer */

    printf("Hello %s\n",s);/*output message to the user*/

    int part = 1;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
      {

        while((isspace(s[i]) || s[i] == '=') && (i < strlen(s)))
          {
            i++;//parse the string for the next portion of the command            
          }

        if(i >= strlen(s))
          {
            printf("Error: Command not properly formatted!\n");
            break;//terminate the for loop
          }        

        if(part == 1)//grab the command
          {
            int size1 = 0;//size of the command
            int j = i;//index of the first non-space character in this portion of the string

            while(!isspace(s[j]))//determine the size of the command, j will point to space when the loop exits
              {
                size1++;
                j++;                            
              }

            Command = (char*) malloc (size1+1);//allocate space to hold the characters of the command along with the terminating '\0' character

            int d = 0;//destination index
            while(i<j)
              {
                Command[d] = s[i];//copy the characters of the command portion of s over to the command array
                d++;
                i++;
              }

            Command[d] = '\0';//terminating null character
            part++;//increment the part of the command

          }
        else if(part == 2)//grab the varname
          {
            int size2 = 0;//initialize the size of the character array which will hold the variable name
            int k = i;
            while(!isspace(s[k]))//determine the size of the varname, k will be at the next space when the loop exits
              {
                size2++;
                k++;                            
              }

            Varname = (char*) malloc (size2+1);//allocate space to hold the characters of the Varname along with the terminating '\0' character

            int e = 0;
            while(i<k)
              {
                Varname[e] = s[i];//copy the characters of the Varname portion of s over to the Varname string
                e++;
                i++;
              }
            Varname[e] = '\0';
            part++;//increment part
          }
        else if(part == 3)//grab the value if one is given
          {
            int size3 = 0;//initialize the size of the character array which will hold the value of the environment variable
            int l = i;
            while(!isspace(s[l]) && s[l] != '\0')//determine the size of the varname and check if we've reached the end of the string
              {
                size3++;
                l++;                            
              }

            Value = (char*) malloc (size3+1);//allocate space to hold the characters of the Value along with the terminating '\0' character
            int f = 0;
            while(i<l)
              {
                Value[f] = s[i];//copy the characters of the command portion of s over to the command array
                f++;
                i++;
              }
            Value[f] = '\0';
          }
      }
    /*print out the sections of the full command*/
    if(Command != NULL)
      {
        printf("Hey %s\n",Command);
      }
    if(Varname != NULL)
      {
        printf("Hey %s\n",Varname);
      }  
    if(Value != NULL)
      {
        printf("Hey %s\n",Value);
      }

    /* clean up! */
    free(s);
    free(Command);
    free(Varname);
    free(Value);
  }
  return(0);
}
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter Name: set ray = 21
Hello set ray = 21
Hey set
Hey ray
Hey 21
Enter Name: print ray
Hello print ray
Hey print
Hey ray
Hey
Enter Name: delete varname
Hello delete varname
Hey delete
Hey varname
Hey delete
Enter Name: print raymond
Hello print raymond
Hey print
Hey raymond
Hey
Enter Name: delete variable
Hello delete variable
Hey delete
Hey variable
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. The second part of your error "core dumped" indicates that the runtime system has generated a "core" file. If you compiled your program  with the `-g` option, `gdb your-progname core` should tell you where your program faulted.

Comment: Slightly related: This is what [`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) was made for, and probably 90% of this code goes away if you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare three pointers without initialising them

```
char * Command;
char * Varname;
char * Value;
```

Depending on the contents of user input, these may not all be initialised to point to dynamically allocated memory inside your `for` loop.  If they aren't all initialised, attempting to `free` them later will likely crash

```
free(Command);
free(Varname);
free(Value);
```

The easiest fix will be to initialise all the variables to `NULL` at the start of processing each line

```
while (s=readline("Enter Name: ")) {
    Command = NULL;
    Varname = NULL;
    Value = NULL;
```

It'll then be safe to call `free` on them, even if they're still set to `NULL`.

Comment: He should null them at the beginning of the loop. Otherwise, they'll still hold the values from the previous iteration, and he'll free them twice.

Comment: Thanks, the indentation in the question caught me out.  I've corrected my answer now.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked.  I had assumed that the pointers would be NULL by default if nothing else was specified.

Comment: @RaymondLemon Glad it helped.  Uninitialised pointers have undefined value.  Typically, they'll pick up whatever value their memory previously held but the only thing that is guaranteed is that dereferencing an uninitialised pointer results in undefined behaviour.